# Move vertices towards/away from camera?

Tags: camera, transform-orientation

I have a flat plane and I want to move some of its vertices (the green ones on the image below) so that visually the plane would stay the same in my camera view.

[image]

I thought I'll simply switch to View Orientation and use Z-axis to move them. However View Z-axis is perpendicular to camera plane, not directed to camera:

[image]

So when I move vertices, their position in the camera view is shifted (green dots are the original vertices positions):

[image]

Can I somehow move them using a camera direction as a Z-axis so that visually my object will stay the same in the camera view? Here I manually moved the vertices to desired positions:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Snap 3D cursor to camera
- Set pivot point to be the 3D cursor
- Select vertices
- Scale them

You don't want to just move them, scaling take into account how far you are from the camera so that your cube will look exactly the same from the camera perspective.

[image: example]

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of that! That worked perfectly

Comment: is there any option for the viewport camera?

Comment: @ThorSummoner You can make a new camera and then "Snap camera to view" and then the steps should work identically